# Using encodeURIComponent in XPages

Tags: replace, xpages, xpages-ssjs, encodeuricomponent

In the W3Schools they give this example:

```
var uri = "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

Which does what I want however, when I run it I get an error that encodeURIComponent is not implemented.

```
try{    
    var str:String = "Contracts and Leases";
    var rtn = encodeURIComponent(str);
}catch(e){
    println(e)
}
```

added the above to a button i get the not implemented error. Is there an equivalent I just need to replace the spaces with %20s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(stringToEncode, "utf-8")` so in your case do this:

```
try{    
    var str:String = "Contracts and Leases";
    var rtn = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(str, "utf-8");
}catch(e){
    println(e)
}
```

Comment: What if we need it for the entire document how do u go about it

Comment: Please clarify. Better yet: post a new question